# Use filter rule to redirect _and_ remove from syslogd

Tags: syslog, rsyslog, rsyslogd

Adding this to /etc/rsyslog.d/myapp.conf helpfully sends messages to a dedicated log file.

```
:programname, isequal, "myapp" /var/log/myapp.log
```

The log messages go in my new log file, but they are also being placed in `/var/log/syslog` as well. How do we prevent this? I have tried this, but it doesn't work:

```
:programname, isequal, "myapp" -/var/log/myapp.log
:programname, isequal, "myapp" /var/log/myapp.log & stop
:programname, isequal, "myapp" -/var/log/myapp.log & stop
```

Comment: You are only allowed one action per line, so put the `& stop` on the next line.

Answer (score 2):

Using trial and error, I have discovered that the following works:

```
:programname, isequal, "myapp" /var/log/myapp.log
:programname, isequal, "myapp" ~
```

**Notes:**

- that newest versions of rsyslog apparently prefer `stop` rather than `~`.
- As per comment above, It may be possible to achieve the same by adding `& stop` on a subsequent line, but I have not tested this.